Unable to update/delete Config Var
I am unable to make updates to config variables to my Python/Django site on Heroku, either using the dashboard or the terminal. I have a Java/Spring app that I can make all the changes I want, no problem. But on this one, can't make any changes
I've tried making a change, it won't stick. I've tried deleting a variable and recreating it, when I refresh the page, the variable I deleted and recreated it back to the original value. I've tried creating a dummy variable, TEST=test, and when I refresh the page it isn't there
I've tried removing all config variables. All that happens is I get a series of messages that the build fails and I'm back to square one because Heroku rebuilds them

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

There is no code that others can better understand. I am using the dashboard

I navigate to ->Settings->Reveal Config Vars
I click on the X to delete a variable
The app rebuilds, fails and restores the variable

I have tried disabling the auto-build, deleting all vars, then manually building. No change, all of the deleted variables are back

We ran into a similar situation when we made environment variable changes that caused the build not to pass. So until we got the build passing, the environment variable changes in the dashboard didn't take effect.
The tricky part is that the build was failing because we had deleted an environment variable previously that was necessary for the build to succeed. So we had to re-add that environment variable to get the build to pass and then all of the environment variable changes that we had been making suddenly showed up.

What I ended up doing was logging into heroku using a terminal on my computer, then force setting all variables at once:
heroku config:set DB_DB=<database_name> DB_PW=<database_password> DB_USER=<database_user> DB_HOST=<database_host> --app=<app> 

This apparently gets past their system changing a variable and checking that everything works before setting the next.
